# How much will it cost MrBeast to send a HDD alongside the new moon rover?

Tags: the-moon, nasa

I saw this mrbeast stream where you could send a pic to the moon and he promises that he has made arrangements with nasa that they (nasa) will pack it up with a new rover to the moon to be launched late 2021.
I am just curious how much does it cost to put something on the moon (including hitching a ride and sending the package separately).
What will be the cost per kg?
Thanks in advance.

Link To the youtube video :

Comment: Electron rocket costs 7.5m for 300 kg to LEO. That makes 25k per kg. The Moon payload should be like 3x more expensive. But Let's say 6x that means 150,000 USD per kg. It should be a good business to send even printed photos. At 100g per photo that makes 15k per photo - a lot of people can afford that.

Comment: @uhoh, I have edited the question to include the video of the mentioned stream.

Comment: @Joe Jobs  What about the landing system?

Comment: No idea about lander weight. Meanwhile I found this: Electron can put 30 kg into Moon Orbit - https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/10/rocket-lab-yep-rocket-lab-has-a-plan-to-deliver-satellites-to-the-moon/

Comment: HDD? Magnetic? A modern SD card has a _much_ better data to weight ratio. It literally weighs a few grams.

Comment: An SD card has 1 TB capacity and less than 1g

Comment: I see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1.2 million/kg from these guys: https://www.astrobotic.com/

MicroSD cards come in 1TB and weigh about 250mg.  Thus you are looking at around $300/TB.

Update:  There's a 1.5TB MicroSD.  Thus $200/TB.